# Custom Parallax in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm in the process of designing my Wordpress website, with extremely basic knowledge of coding. I've finished designing the home and content pages, however, only one action is pending.

I would like to include the parallax effect included below, on my home page, but not as the header. My webpage begins with the header, then the navigation bar, and then I would like to create a section including the parallax effect linked above, with 4 different layers.

**CSS:**

```
@import "compass/css3";

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body{
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

.parallax {
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

.parallax__cover{
  background: #2D112B;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
}

$parallax__layers: 6;

@for $i from 0 through $parallax__layers {
  $x: ($parallax__layers - $i) / 2;
  .parallax__layer__#{$i}{
     transform: translateZ(-100 * $x#{px}) scale($x + 1);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
      </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
    <img src="data:image/png;image URL here"/>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
    <img src="data:image/png;image URL here"/>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
    <img src="data:image/png;image URL here"/>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
    <img src="data:image/png;image URL here"/>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
    <img src="data:image/png;image URL here"/>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
    <img src="data:image/png;image URL here"/>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__cover"></div>
</div>
```

Can you kindly guide me with achieving this?

Comment: Some HTML code to see the structure would go a long way in helping us solve this!

Comment: Included in the question now :)